# hide published node's field?

Tags: entities, theming

I want to hide one of a node's field when the node was published. I copied and renamed the node.tpl.php as node--app.tpl.php cause the node's content type's machine name is app.

I tested it by add the code at the beginning of the node--app.tpl.php file. yeah it works.

```
<?php print $node->field__iap_dl['und'][0]['url']; ?>
```

In order to hide the field I added one line in the existing code.

```
<div class="content clearfix"<?php print $content_attributes; ?>>

<?php
  // We hide the comments and links now so that we can render them later.
  hide($content['comments']);
  hide($content['links']);
  hide($content['field__ipa_dl']);    // I added!
  print render($content);
?>
</div>
```

This time it didn't work. What's wrong? I am newbie to code the Drupal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not tell it to hide `$node->field__iap_dl['und'][0]['url']`.

The field probably did not show up in the rendered content, but it will still appear if you tell the template to print the information directly from the node object.

The simplest way to hide a field is to go to /admin/structure/types and under manage fields for the content type, mark the field as hidden.

EDIT:

Is this a cut and paste of your code? If so the fields names are different. **field__iap_dl** is not the same as **field__ipa_dl**.

Comment: ?? I want to hide the whole field. Sorry I didn't quite follow u.

Comment: I also read the article http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12514424/how-to-hide-field-from-preprocess-node-in-drupal-7
@Nikhil M   I use the default theme bartik

Comment: Yes  @Triskelion , as i said , the first line of code works,It print the contend ( $node->field__iap_dl['und'][0]['url'])

so i think i should use $content['field__ipa_dl']. 

and I also sure for it because i see it in the Devel Module.

Comment: Why u said the the names are different. I use the same name.@Triskelion

Comment: The spellings are different. ipa and iap. If the code in your question is the same as the code in your file, then you did NOT use the same name. If you correct the spelling it might work.

Comment: you are right,a stupid fault,the spelling !!! ,I correct it and it works.  Thanks @ Triskelion

Comment: Triskelion, one more Q: I want to judge the user's OS, yes maybe i would say the requirement is : To show the Field due to the user's OS,say, if the user use Apple device(iPhone,iPad,itouch) we show it the Install APP field,otherwise show the Download field. Now i need a judgment condition,cause i have realized the hide field,Can u give me some suggestions

Comment: I want to judge the device's OS to decide which field to appears